# Cannot read text file using csv?

Tags: r, csv

I have a text data separated ny "commas" i.e.",". The sample of the data is given below (first row indicates the column names):

```
userID,appName,startTime,endTime,endResult
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 02:47:16,2012-07-01 02:47:46,1
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 03:11:46,2012-07-01 03:12:25,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 03:13:36,2012-07-01 03:14:03,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 03:18:26,2012-07-01 03:18:58,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 04:10:36,2012-07-01 04:10:54,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 04:38:26,2012-07-01 04:38:48,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 04:48:56,2012-07-01 04:49:04,3
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 05:49:46,2012-07-01 05:50:14,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 06:19:07,2012-07-01 06:19:25,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 07:09:17,2012-07-01 07:09:47,2
```

I am using the following syntax:

```
appsession <- read.table("C:/.../AppSession.txt", sep = ",", 
  col.names = c("userID","appName","startTime","endTime","endResult"), 
  fill = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 5 elements
```

Comment: Try: `read.csv("C/Document/.....", header=TRUE)` Does that work?

Comment: but the data is text file.. so i did not try .csv

Comment: A csv file is text file. It just indicates that the values have been separated by a comma.

Comment: I just used read.csv but none of the observations are read. I printed first 20 obs and this is how it comes:   userID appName startTime endTime endResult
1      NA      NA        NA      NA        NA
2      NA      NA        NA      NA        NA
3      NA      NA        NA      NA        NA
4      NA      NA        NA      NA        NA
5      NA      NA        NA      NA        NA
6      NA      NA        NA      NA        NA
7      NA      NA        NA      NA        NA

Comment: Are those blank lines intentional? line 1, if 0-based would refer to a blank line ie. naturally would cause an error as there are no elements there. Try to remove those. A guess from my part as I'm not sure at what level the strip.white removes white space (if it includes blank lines or work isolated on each element). (TIP: You can remove just the first blank line - if the error moves to line 2 then you know for certain it's those blank lines)

Comment: No I have used the blank lines within each observation to make it easier for the reader to read...

Comment: "easier for the reader to read..." here? Or in your file in general? If the former it is best to show the data structure exactly (hence my edit to the question). If the blank lines are in your actual data, then create the file without them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using suitably edited version of your data (i.e. removing all the blank lines!), this can be loaded into R easily via `read.csv()`. Note here I'm using a text connection containing the data to avoid writing your data to a file. Just replace `con` with your file name in the `read.csv()`.

```
con <- textConnection("userID,appName,startTime,endTime,endResult
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 02:47:16,2012-07-01 02:47:46,1
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 03:11:46,2012-07-01 03:12:25,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 03:13:36,2012-07-01 03:14:03,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 03:18:26,2012-07-01 03:18:58,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 04:10:36,2012-07-01 04:10:54,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 04:38:26,2012-07-01 04:38:48,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 04:48:56,2012-07-01 04:49:04,3
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 05:49:46,2012-07-01 05:50:14,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 06:19:07,2012-07-01 06:19:25,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 07:09:17,2012-07-01 07:09:47,2
")

dat <- read.csv(con,
                colClasses = c(rep("character", 2), rep("POSIXct", 2),
                               "numeric"))
close(con) ## closing connection, not needed with a file
```

Also note that by specifying the `colclasses` argument we tell R what the data are before reading them in which saves some formatting later, especially with the DateTime data. We can do this here because you have the DateTime variables stored in the correct format.

```
R> head(dat)
   userID      appName           startTime             endTime endResult
1 chhieut gms.mos.test 2012-07-01 02:47:16 2012-07-01 02:47:46         1
2 chhieut gms.mos.test 2012-07-01 03:11:46 2012-07-01 03:12:25         2
3 chhieut gms.mos.test 2012-07-01 03:13:36 2012-07-01 03:14:03         2
4 chhieut gms.mos.test 2012-07-01 03:18:26 2012-07-01 03:18:58         2
5 chhieut gms.mos.test 2012-07-01 04:10:36 2012-07-01 04:10:54         2
6 chhieut gms.mos.test 2012-07-01 04:38:26 2012-07-01 04:38:48         2
R> str(dat)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ userID   : chr  "chhieut" "chhieut" "chhieut" "chhieut" ...
 $ appName  : chr  "gms.mos.test" "gms.mos.test" "gms.mos.test" "gms.mos.test" ...
 $ startTime: POSIXct, format: "2012-07-01 02:47:16" "2012-07-01 03:11:46" ...
 $ endTime  : POSIXct, format: "2012-07-01 02:47:46" "2012-07-01 03:12:25" ...
 $ endResult: num  1 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2
```

Comment: @ Gavin... I used the following code: > appsession <- read.csv("C:/Documents and Settings/Arundhati.Mukherjee/My Documents/Arundhati/big data/MB07_Arundhati/AppSession.txt",
+ conClasses = c(rep("character",2), rep("POSIXct",2), "numeric"))

Comment: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  unused argument(s) (conClasses = c("character", "character", "POSIXct", "POSIXct", "numeric")).. This is the error I got

Comment: It is `colClasses`, not `conClasses`! The error even tells you that you supplied an unused argument. Do check you have copied the code correctly.

Comment: Warning message:
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  cols = 1 != length(data) = 5

Comment: and the data looks like: ÿþu structure(c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",  structure(c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
1                                                                                                                                       NA
2

Comment: Sorry, but unless you can post the first few lines of your data how can we possibly help you. With correctly formatted text data `read.csv()` **works**. So the problem is your data. Without seeing some of it we will be unable to help. What is that output you just posted? We need to see the first few lines of the text file!

Comment: this is the link where I have uploaded a sample of the data

Comment: I can read that data just fine with the code I showed. `read.csv("sample_data.txt", ....)` where `....` is the `colClasses` code I showed. So the problem is elsewhere in the data set. Do as @DWin mentioned and try `count.fields("sample_data.txt", sep = ",")` and look to see if any rows have different number of fields. That will point you to the row(s) in the file that are incorrect. I strongly suspect that your problem is an unescaped `,` in one of the text fields. Up to you to check this now as you have all the data.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use `skip = 2` if you have a blank line and are planning on using 'col.names' without using `header=TRUE`. At the moment your code works (well sort of works anyway) with a simple text read"

```
> txt <- "userID,appName,startTime,endTime,endResult
+ chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 02:47:16,2012-07-01 02:47:46,1
+ chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 03:11:46,2012-07-01 03:12:25,2
+ chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 03:13:36,2012-07-01 03:14:03,2
+ chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 03:18:26,2012-07-01 03:18:58,2
+ chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 04:10:36,2012-07-01 04:10:54,2
+ chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 04:38:26,2012-07-01 04:38:48,2
+ chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 04:48:56,2012-07-01 04:49:04,3
+ chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 05:49:46,2012-07-01 05:50:14,2
+ chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 06:19:07,2012-07-01 06:19:25,2
+ chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 07:09:17,2012-07-01 07:09:47,2
+ "
> appsession <- read.table(text=txt, sep = ",", 
+   col.names = c("userID","appName","startTime","endTime","endResult"), 
+   fill = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)
> 
> appsession
    userID      appName           startTime             endTime endResult
1   userID      appName           startTime             endTime endResult
2  chhieut gms.mos.test 2012-07-01 02:47:16 2012-07-01 02:47:46         1
3  chhieut gms.mos.test 2012-07-01 03:11:46 2012-07-01 03:12:25         2
4  chhieut gms.mos.test 2012-07-01 03:13:36 2012-07-01 03:14:03         2
5  chhieut gms.mos.test 2012-07-01 03:18:26 2012-07-01 03:18:58         2
6  chhieut gms.mos.test 2012-07-01 04:10:36 2012-07-01 04:10:54         2
7  chhieut gms.mos.test 2012-07-01 04:38:26 2012-07-01 04:38:48         2
8  chhieut gms.mos.test 2012-07-01 04:48:56 2012-07-01 04:49:04         3
9  chhieut gms.mos.test 2012-07-01 05:49:46 2012-07-01 05:50:14         2
10 chhieut gms.mos.test 2012-07-01 06:19:07 2012-07-01 06:19:25         2
11 chhieut gms.mos.test 2012-07-01 07:09:17 2012-07-01 07:09:47         2
```

You should either use header or skip the header row (plus skipping any blank rows.) One way to see how many rows are blank is to look at the output of `countfields( ..., sep=",")`. Another way to see what the `read.*` and `scan` functions are "seeing" would be to execute this code (with suitable replacement of the ellipsis):

```
appLines <- readLines("C:/.../AppSession.txt")
appLines[1:5] # will display the first 5 lines from that file 
              # with no attempt to deal with any separators.
```

Comment: there are no blank rows in my original data.... i just used them to help reader understand the observations

Comment: As I wrote: Use `count.fields` ... even if you think there are no blank rows it will show you how many fields the `scan` function is detecting row by row.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to provide a link to your actual data set, since the data you have provided works fine:

```
d = read.csv(textConnection("userID,appName,startTime,endTime,endResult
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 02:47:16,2012-07-01 02:47:46,1
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 03:11:46,2012-07-01 03:12:25,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 03:13:36,2012-07-01 03:14:03,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 03:18:26,2012-07-01 03:18:58,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 04:10:36,2012-07-01 04:10:54,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 04:38:26,2012-07-01 04:38:48,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 04:48:56,2012-07-01 04:49:04,3
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 05:49:46,2012-07-01 05:50:14,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 06:19:07,2012-07-01 06:19:25,2
chhieut,gms.mos.test,2012-07-01 07:09:17,2012-07-01 07:09:47,2"), header=TRUE)
```

Quick check:

```
R> head(d, 1)
   userID      appName           startTime             endTime endResult
1 chhieut gms.mos.test 2012-07-01 02:47:16 2012-07-01 02:47:46         1
R> dim(d)
[1] 10  5
```

Make sure you don't have blank lines in your actual file - this will really stuff things up.

Comment: Can you save the same data in text format and see the solution? My dta is huge and I caoot upload it anywhere for some security reason

Comment: Can you load your file into Excel?

Comment: @user1702490 The data above and the other questions *are* in text format. As far as R is concerned `read.csv()` is being supplied with the same set of bytes with the connection as it would if the data were loaded from a file. A file is less easy to show as a reproducible example. Just replace the `textConnection(...)` bit with the filename. Try it with the first 100 lines of the data and if that works  then you know there is a problem later in the file so check the formatting etc.

Comment: not possible.. because it has more than 3 million observations